# NSOperation - Group operations and wait until all of them are finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I have a subclass of NSOperation and NSOperationQueue object. My operations look the same, I am adding all in OperationQueue and perform completion block after finishing each operation. But some operations are members of one business-group, and this group may be simultaneously performed in queue. I need to wait, until each group finish and perform completion block after each group is finished. But I don't want to block groups or running one after another. How can I make this variant using NSOperation or with the help of other approaches.

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one operation that depends from each of your operations and wait until all operations finished

```
    NSOperationQueue* queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

NSOperation* finalOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"ALL IS DONE!");
}];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSOperation* op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"%zd", i);
    }];
    [finalOperation addDependency:op];
    [queue addOperation:op];
}
 [queue addOperation:finalOperation];
```

---

```
Output: 
0
2
3
1
5
4
6
7
8
9
ALL IS DONE!
```